# Customize crispy form for django-filter

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms, django-filter

I'm trying to customize form in django using [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) extensions. Here is my form snippet:

```
class FilterForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'get'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Div('country', css_class='col-sm-3'),
                Div('brand', css_class='col-sm-3'),
            )
        )
```

This is how the layout looks like in browser:

[image]

So my questions are: how do I remove `p` tag with "Filter" text in it and why the arrow button of select control shrinks like this?

Comment: How did you tie in the crispy forms and the django filters?

Comment: @KronoS you just passing usual form attribute to your filter. Crispy rendering occurs in template when you `load crispy_tags` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable paragraph with help text I used this setting

```
FILTERS_HELP_TEXT_FILTER = False
```

The style of select box has to do with the bootstrap/firefox issue. Workaround is to restyle select box in css.